# Rails application settings and tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, settings, settingslogic

In my app I've used [SettingsLogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic) to handle the app's settings (such as facebook tokens etc.) which is a gem that basically parses the config/application.yml file and provides easy access to its content.

**I've** also **used this configuration file to enable or disable i18n support for the entire app**, as the app is more of a core app for many child apps.

And so in my **routes.rb** I do things like :

```
if Settings.i18n.enabled
  match ':this', :to => 'that#place'
end
```

Or in **models** :

```
if Settings.i18n.enabled
  scope :for_current_locale, lambda { where(:locale => I18n.locale) }
end
```

**I'd like to test how the app responds to both states : when i18n is turned off and when it is turned on.**

My problem is that the state is read from the configuration file when Rails initializes. So when I run my tests I could only run tests related to i18n.enabled being false, then change my configuration file and run tests related to i18n.enabled being true.

Is there some way I could reinitialize the app between 2 tests ? (I'm using Rspec)
Or should I automate some way of running 2 separate tests files for both i18n cases ?
Or maybe there is a better way ?

Thanks !

**EDIT**

As for the routes issue I managed to make the specs pass by changing my settings and reloading the routes explicitly :

```
before(:all) do
  Settings.i18n["enabled"] = true
  My::Application.reload_routes!
end
```

But still I feel this is not ideal, and what about things defined in models ? Can I reload my models as well before running specs ? Won't that duplicate stuff like callbacks ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you simple can reconfigure your Application like following, for example in a rspec before_all block in your specific test file:

```
YourAppName::Application.configure do
  config.i18n.enabled = true # or false
end
```

And in an after_all block you can set the configuration back to your default one.
I think that could work.

Comment: Actually it doesn't. Since the before/after block is executed after Rails is loaded.